# macOS Swift monitoring global events not working for generic keyDown

Tags: macos, events, swift4

I did set the necessary privileges for the app, and for some events it is working.

For instance:

`NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: .flagsChanged) {
    print("\($0)")
}`

works, but

`NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown) {
    print("\($0)")
}`

doesn't.

So I am wondering, is it possible at all to listen globally for any keypress?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After checking the privileges via

`let accessEnabled = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(
            [kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt.takeUnretainedValue() as String: true] as CFDictionary)`

I found out, that due to the program running through the Xcode debugger granting the privileges to the app was not enough, I also had to give the privileges to Xcode itself.

Comment: Wow! You saved my week! I had spent so much time to figure this out! Thanks A lot man!

Comment: Working for intel mac but m1 mac its not working, any idea?

Answer (score 3):

schnesim is right!!!
but one thing that the answer failed to mention is that every time you change something in a running section of code, you have to go back into preferences and disable, then reenable the permission for the app(not for xcode though) I struggled with that for hours.

Comment: To future readers: A fix for that is located here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49716420/adding-a-global-monitor-with-nseventmaskkeydown-mask-does-not-trigger

Comment: It will ask you for your password on every build, but you can fix that by selecting "always allow" on the prompt